# String Alignment calculation different in R and Python

Tags: r, python-3.x, text

I am trying to calculate the Optimal String Alignment similarity score between two strings. However, the same measure gives two different values with R(using stringdist library) and Python(using textdistance library).

In python

```
import textdistance as td
print(td.lcsstr.normalized_similarity('africa', 'abc africa')) #Gives 0.6
```

In R

```
require(stringdist)
stringsim('africa', 'abc africa', method = 'lcs') # Gives 0.75
```

Is there a difference between how the normalised similarity is calculated or the back end implementation of the algorithm?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the normalised longest common substring similarity between two strings, in this case 'africa' and 'abc Africa'. I am confused as to why my output is different in R and Python. Is there a difference between the back end algorithms used to calculate so in the two libraries?

Comment: Yes there is. You see it from your output. Dig into the sources if you like to compare implementations - or read the documentation. From a cursory glance the python implementation it [removes f.e. junk characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) - (( wich is kinda irrelevant as your text is too short to be applied)) but thats somethign the doku of [R - dist-metrics](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringdist/versions/0.9.5.1/topics/stringdist-metrics) does not mention at all... so there are diffs.